# Last bin of histogram missing

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

First, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297630/missing-last-bin-in-histogram-plot-from-matplot-python) answer does not work for me, but the problem is essentially the same. My data `x` is a list in the range [-2:18], labeled as [A:U]. The last bin (17 or T) is actually accumulating the number of values of 17-T and 18-U, showing bin 18-U empty.

My code looks like this (aesthetics have been omitted, `x` was read from a .csv):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)

Labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
       'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']
bins = len(Labels)
ax.hist(x, bins=bins, density=False, histtype='step', color='grey', linewidth=2) 
ax.set_xticklabels(Labels)

plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

Trying the existing solution, `bins = len(Labels) + 1` does not make any difference.

Comment: The code you show cannot produce the figure you show. At some place you additionally manipulate the positions/labels, making everything wrong. Also read the linked solution closely: They do not specify the number of bins, but the actual bin edges!

Comment: For simplicity I omitted some parts of the customisation, I wanted to highlight the part in which I set the labels. If the labels specify the bin *edges* and not their number, I don't understand why behaves like that in the penultimate value of the list of bins.

Comment: Your labels have nothing to do with the bins or bin edges (you see that e.g. between H and I). Without [mcve] I cannot help you solve this.